# sql update giving wrong results

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following sql statement in VB.NET

```
   Dim READER As SqlDataReader

    Try
        konneksie.Open()
        Dim Query As String

        Query = "Update blokkeklaar " & _
        " set Klaarvb = 'JA' " & _
        " where KlaarEZY = 'YES'" & _
        " Update blokkeklaar " & _
        " set Klaarvb = 'NEE' " & _
        "  where KlaarVB IS NULL"

        COMMAND = New SqlCommand(Query, konneksie)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("KlaarVB verander ")
        konneksie.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
    End Try
    konneksie.Close()
```

I cannot understand why klaarvb is populated with "NEE" where klaarvb is not null?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted sample data from before and after your update statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do 2 separate updates with one statement. If you want a single statement solution, try:

```
update blokkeklaar 
set Klaarvb = case
                when KlaarEZY = 'YES' then 'JA' 
                when KlaarVB is null then 'NEE' 
                else Klaarvb -- Thanks hurcane
              end;
```

This evaluates in order, and exits when condition is met, so if the first condition is true, the second will not be evaluated or applied.

Comment: Without an Else on the case condition, I believe Klaarvb will be set to null if it was not null before the statement was executed. To preserve data, you should have an "else Klaarvb".

Answer (score 2):

you have to put semicolon between the statements or execute them separately:

```
 Query = "Update blokkeklaar " & _
        " set Klaarvb = 'JA' " & _
        " where KlaarEZY = 'YES';" & _ //<--put semiColon here
        " Update blokkeklaar " & _
        " set Klaarvb = 'NEE' " & _
        "  where KlaarVB IS NULL"
```

Also as a side note, you better use  `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteReader`

Comment: Strictly speaking, SQL will execute these two statements exactly the same with or without the semi-colon. Whitespace is sufficient to separate the commands. Semi-colon is only required when the syntax between commands is ambiguous. For these two update statements, there is no ambiguity.